# User authentication using an Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, authentication, encryption, oracle-ebs

I'm having some trouble with decrypting the `ENCRYPTED_USER_PASSWORD` field in an Oracle database. Pretty new to using Oracle, so could anyone please shed some light on how to go about getting the plain text password back.

I've had a look around online and found these steps:

1. The `ENCRYPTED_FOUNDATION_PASSWORD` and `ENCRYPTED_USER_PASSWORD` are retrieved from `FND_USER` if the account exists and is active.
2. The `APPS` password is obtained from `ENCRYPTED_FOUNDATION_PASSWORD` by using the username and password as the decryption key.
3. The user password is decrypted from `ENCRYPTED_USER_PASSWORD` by using the `APPS` password as the decryption key.
4. The decrypted user password is compared to the entered user password.

I'm under the impression that we need to use this `decrypt` function, but have no clue on which one (from which library) I'm meant to use, and a use case for it.

Could anyone provide a detailed explanation on how to go about using the decrypt function / SQL query I need to run please?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do - integrate your own application with EBS? Have a separate application that uses EBS credentials? Something else?

Comment: Yes. We have a separate application which we need to validate a user the first time they login with their existing credentials from the Oracle database

Comment: *getting the plain text password back* this is not possible.

Comment: @SudiptaMondal It should be. The password is not hashed, it's encrypted.